# Pi calculator outputing 0

Tags: java

I am building a series of small programs for practice. I am building a Pi calculator to practice numbers. However, when I run the program the result is zero. No errors are thrown. More than likely the answer is obvious, and I will end up banging my head against the wall.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class FindPi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal answer = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal counts = new BigDecimal(5);
        BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(2);
        for (BigDecimal k = new BigDecimal(0); k.compareTo(counts) <= 0; k = k.add(BigDecimal.ONE)) {
            BigDecimal a = k.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
            BigDecimal b = factorial(BigDecimal.ONE.add(k.multiply(two)));
            BigDecimal d = a.divide(b, 10, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
            answer = answer.add(d);
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }

    public static BigDecimal factorial(BigDecimal n) {
        BigDecimal fact = new BigDecimal(1);
        for (BigDecimal x = n; x.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) > 0; x = x.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE)) {
            fact = fact.multiply(x);
        }
        return fact;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the right time to start a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Just ran one. here is the console: Listening on javadebug
User program running
User program finished

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong with the iterations using BigDecimal

Comment: Alexander (and everyone else viewing this question) would like you to step through the code in a debugger. Make sure your loop iterates as many times as you expect, verify variable values, etc.

Comment: I don't get zero when I run this.  I don't get the right answer, but I don't get zero.

Comment: Caffeine, it looks like you may not using the debugger correctly. Are you stepping through? Are you watching the key variables?

Comment: This doesn't look like any formula for calculating π that I've ever seen.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels you are probably right.

Comment: I think this formula is computing e/2, not π.  The program appears to compute the formula correctly, though, when I try it.  It's baffling to me that you're getting zero when you run it, unless you haven't installed something correctly.

Comment: @tobias_k But it doesn't answer why the OP is getting zero.

Comment: Oops, I put in the formula for the other program I was making!

Comment: Netbeans has been giving me a lot of trouble lately, maybe the problem is my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was my IDE, not my code, running it in eclipse Not sure why it wasn't working, but I think it's time to say bye-bye to Netbeans.